# Does 'Spring Session' support 'Web Session Clustering'?

Tags: spring, spring-session

Does 'Spring Session' support 'Web Session Clustering' across multiple App Server container ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. One of the main motivations of Spring Session is providing clustered sessions that are not tied to a specific application server.

See [Http Session with Redis](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html5/#httpsession-redis) for an example.

Another suggestion is using the [MapSessionRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html5/#api-mapsessionrepository) with a distributed map implementation such as Hazelcast.